# Group by linq for nested objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a group by linq statement where i convert a single list of data into an list with a nested list. Here is my code so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LinqTestNestedSelect2()
{
    // initialization 
    List<combi> listToLinq = new List<combi>() { 
        new combi{ id = 1, desc = "a", name = "A", count = 1 },
        new combi{ id = 1, desc = "b", name = "A", count = 2 },
        new combi{ id = 2, desc = "c", name = "B", count = 3 },
        new combi{id = 2,  desc = "d", name = "B", count = 4 },
    };

    // linq group by
    var result = (from row in listToLinq
                  group new { des = row.desc, count = row.count } by new { name = row.name, id = row.id } into obj
                  select new A { name = obj.Key.name, id = obj.Key.id, descriptions = (from r in obj select new B() { des = r.des, count = r.count }).ToList() }).ToList();

    // validation of the results
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result[0].descriptions.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result[0].descriptions.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result[1].descriptions.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result[1].descriptions.Count);
}

public class A
{
    public int id;
    public string name;

    public List<B> descriptions;
}

public class B
{
    public int count;
    public string des;
}

public class combi
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int count;
    public string desc;
}
```

This is fine if the objects are small like the example. However I will implement this for objects with a lot more properties. How can I efficiently write this statement so I don't have to write field names twice in my linq statement?

I would like to return the objects in the statement and I want something like:

```
// not working wishfull thinking code 
var result = (from row in listToLinq
              group new { des = row.desc, count = row.count } by new { name = row.name, id = row.id } into obj
              select new (A){ this = obj.key , descriptions = obj.ToList<B>()}).ToList();
```

**Background**: I am re writing a web api that retrieves objects with nested objects in a single database call for the sake of db performance. It's basically a big query with a join that retrieves a crap load of data which I need to sort out into objects.
**probably important**: the ID is unique.

**EDIT:** 
based on the answers so far I have made a solution which sort of works for me, but is still a bit ugly, and I would want it to be better looking.

```
{
    // start part
    return (from row in reader.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.id into grouping
            select CreateA(grouping)).ToList();
}

private static A CreateA(IGrouping<object, listToLinq> grouping)
{
     A retVal = StaticCreateAFunction(grouping.First());
    retVal.descriptions = grouping.Select(item => StaticCreateBFunction(item)).ToList();
    return ret;
}
```

I hope the StaticCreateAFunction is obvious enough for what it does. In this scenario I only have to write out each property once, which is what I really wanted. But I hope there is a more clever or linq-ish way to write this.

Comment: Does A only have these 2 properties (and the collection)? Or does it have more?

Comment: A will have 10 or more properties. However, the id is unique

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from row in listToLinq
              group new B { des = row.desc, count = row.count } by new A { name = row.name, id = row.id } into obj
              select new A { name = obj.Key.name, id = obj.Key.id, descriptions = obj.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Comment: I still need to write all the properties for class A twice in this example. and then I also need to change the classes to structs for the tests to pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to each of the `A` and `B` classes a constructor that receives a `combi` and then it takes from it only what it needs. For example for `a`:

```
public class A
{
    public A(combi c)
    {
        id = c.id;
        name = c.name;
    }
}   

public class B
{
    public B(combi c)
    {
        count = c.count;
        des = c.desc;
    }
}
```

Then your query can look like:

```
var result = (from row in listToLinq
              group row by new { row.id, row.name } into grouping
              select new A(grouping.First())
              {
                  descriptions = grouping.Select(item => new B(item)).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

*If you don't like the `grouping.First()` you can then override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and then in the `group by` do by a new `a` with the relevant fields (which will be those in the `Equals`) and then add a `copy constructor` from `a`*

Another way, in which you decouple the `A`/`B` classes from the `combi` is to extract the convert logic to a collection of static methods.

Comment: This effectively reduces my work by half. I still have to write out all the property settings of class A twice. And it will also require all my classes to know of the combi class. I will most likely have to deal with this issue multiple times, so the cleaner the better.

Comment: @martijn - you have to have the code of converting a `combi` to `A`\`B` somewhere... But about knowing the `combi` you are right - and what you can do for that is have a collection of static convert methods

Comment: Good point about the static convert methods, i will keep that in mind. does the First method have performance issues? Will it slow my code down on large scale use?

Comment: @martijn - Not sure.. grouping might be a more costly operations but as a rule of thumb with performance issues - first have them and only then try and fix (this doesn't mean to not optimize where it is simple and obvious.